# How to print spaces in between within a pattern in 8086 (Assembly)?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, tasm, dosbox, ascii-art

perhaps this is a question that has already been answered. I am trying to create a parallelogram pattern in assembly with hearts, it works but sadly whenever I try to add the spaces between the characters; most of them disappear. I'm thinking that it's because of the CL register or maybe I have overlooked some parts. I have tried different trials and errors to get the expected output. Unfortunately, I am still a beginner in this push-and-pop method so please bear with the comments. Also, this was a code for a right triangle that I've tweaked to become a parallelogram.

I emulated this using TASM-TLINK on DOSBOX.

Here's the code below:

```
.MODEL TINY
.386
.DATA
.CODE
    ORG 100H

BEGIN:
    MOV BL,4
    MOV CL,4
    
    ;    * * * *
    ;   * * * *
    ;  * * * *          ; THE EXPECTED PATTERN
    ; * * * *
    
    ;PUSH BX 
    
    L1:
    PUSH CX
    MOV AH,2
    MOV DL,20H ;INCREMENT SPACES
    
    ;SPACE:
    ;MOV AH,02
    ;MOV DL,20H
    ;INT 21H
    
    ;LOOP SPACE 
    ;POP CX 
       
    L2:
     INT 21H
     LOOP L2 
     
     MOV CL,BL 
     DEC CL
     MOV AH,2 ; PRINT THE CHARACTERS
     MOV DL,03H
     INT 21H
     ;MOV AH,02
     ;MOV DL,20H
     ;INT 21H
     
    L3:
     INT 21H
     LOOP L3 
     
     MOV AH,2 ; GENERATE NEW LINES
     MOV DL,10
     INT 21H
     MOV DL,13
     INT 21H

    DEC BH ; DECREMENT BH REGISTER TO TRIM PARALLELOGRAM 
    ;INC BH?
    POP CX
    ;PUSH BX 
    
    LOOP L1
       
    
    EXIT:
    MOV AH,4CH
    INT 21H
    INT 20H

END BEGIN
```

Thank you to anyone who takes the time to answer this. All good wishes!

Comment: `DEC BH` should of course be `DEC BL`. Also the `POP CX` will overwrite the decremented `CX` value so that needs to go (along with the `PUSH CX`). There may be more errors, the code is hard to follow.

Comment: Thank you so much! I had to reorganize most of the code actually and finally was able to put spaces in between the characters. I had push through a lot of infinite loops just to finally get the one that I've needed. Thank you for the hint.

Answer (score 1):

### Some fine points

> ```
> MOV BL,4
> MOV CL,4
> ```

Because your program will be using the `loop` instruction that depends on **the whole 16 bits** of the `CX` register, you should setup via `mov cx, 4` and not rely on your environment starting from an emptied register!

> ```
> DEC BH ; DECREMENT BH REGISTER TO TRIM PARALLELOGRAM 
> ;INC BH?
> ```

You don't need this instruction at all. There is nothing to trim here! The dimension of the parallelogram that you have set in the `BL` register **remains constant**.

> ```
> EXIT:
> MOV AH,4CH
> INT 21H
> INT 20H
> ```

The `mov ah, 4Ch` `int 21h` DOS.TerminateWithReturncode already ended your program. The `int 20h` DOS.TerminateProgram **will never execute** and so is totally useless here.

---

[Your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72982014/how-to-print-spaces-in-between-within-a-pattern-in-8086-assembly#comment128904820_72982014) indicates that you have succesfully rewritten your program. Nonetheless, please take a look at my solution below:

```
    MOV  AH, 02h   ; DOS.PrintCharacter
    MOV  BX, 4     ; Dimension of the parallelogram, 2 or more
    MOV  CX, BX    ; Leading whitespace
L1: PUSH CX        ; (1)
    MOV  DL, ' '
L2: INT  21h
    DEC  CX
    JNZ  L2

    MOV  DL, 3     ; Heart
    INT  21h
    LEA  CX, [BX-1]
L3: MOV  DL, ' '
    INT  21h
    MOV  DL, 3     ; Heart
    INT  21h
    DEC  CX
    JNZ  L3

    MOV  DL, 10
    INT  21h
    MOV  DL, 13
    INT  21h

    POP  CX        ; (1)
    DEC  CX
    JNZ  L1
```

So you don't have to un-learn it latter, you refrain from using the `loop` instruction. See [Why is the loop instruction slow? Couldn't Intel have implemented it efficiently?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35742570/why-is-the-loop-instruction-slow-couldnt-intel-have-implemented-it-efficiently)?

Expected output (4 spaces start first line):

```
    ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
   ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
  ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
 ♥ ♥ ♥ ♥
```

Comment: @Serena Was this answer useful to you?